# fetchting the values from pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am making a social networking type website and i have added a follow button.on clicking of the button the user id and friend id is stored in the database,now i want to retrieve the value of those people that user is following.so i am using session to get user_id and passing it to model to fetch the id of those users which are being followed.
my model is

```
public function display_following($user_id)
{
    $this->db->select('username,country,designation');
    $this->db->from('user_login');

    $this->db->join('friends','friends.friend_id=user_login.id');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows()>0){
        return $query->result();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

basically i am asking for the content of users that are being followed so i am comparing the user_id and and fetching friend_id and then getting data from user_login  table of these people.my controller is

```
public function display_following(){
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id'];
    $this->load->model('Main_Model');
    $this->Main_Model->display_following($user_id);
    $following=$this->Main_Model->display_following();
    $this->load->view('following',$following);
}
```

Severity: Warning

> Message: Missing argument 1 for Main_Model::display_following(),
>   called in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ask/application/controllers/Main.php on
>   line 110 and defined
>
> Filename: models/Main_Model.php
>
> Line Number: 42

Answer (score 0):

Pass `$user_id` in `display_following function` and remove then line which is just calling this function,

```
public function display_following(){
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id'];
    $this->load->model('Main_Model');
    ///$this->Main_Model->display_following($user_id);// comment/remove this line
    $following=$this->Main_Model->display_following($user_id); // pass $user_id in display_following()
    $this->load->view('following',$following);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to pass your argument $user_id as a parameter when calling your function

```
$following=$this->Main_Model->display_following();
```

Replace by

```
$following=$this->Main_Model->display_following($user_id);
```